# Type the returnType of a function that receive dynamic args

Tags: typescript

I have a function that receives `args` that can be either typed as `string` or as `[string, Record<string, string>]`.

This function returns an object for which the keys are either the args of the function if these args are typed `string` or the first string in the array if these arg are typed `[string, Record<string, string>]`. All the values of this object are typed as `string`

For example :

```
exampleFunction("test1", "test2", ["test3", { result: "randomstring" }], "test4");
```

should return something typed like this:

```
type tResult = {
  test1: string;
  test2: string;
  test3: string;
  test4: string;
};
```

This function can take any amount of args and any of those args can be either `string` or `[string, Record<string, string>]`.

The challenge is to type the returnType of this `exampleFunction`.

[Typescript sandbox  link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBMCiAeBDAtmANhAYgVwHYGNgBLAe1wEEAnAcygF4oBtAZ2EqN2oBooAlCfCUoATADyt2nHhI7UAfAF0A3ACgVoSDAQp0WPIVIUazelCqVEIcW1lQAPlqSoMOAsTJV5q9eGhwnuq4GZPzA2JS4ogAqUBDwwBC4wib+Oi767kbUzHKm-IIioipQUFGMuNjIAEYQlAqx8YnJUDKcUAD8peWVNXVQAFxdFdW1CowADApcxS02nCpyaoK4rA1pem6GptENCUkp2s4bwVk5ABQAdFeIxoNRAJT0uQDeM5QQYRFQN9kX78LYfAQM5nRD4fA8H6DVq0BypI5BTKeR50F4zEpEABmUDOGggJGxP3oDAARDCSY9XiVqVB3p9cFAqTTqVcLmCIejmYwfgpBiSLEkSMhydNmVAAL6qGni2JoZjQJk0unhBmK5ms9misVMH4TBS8740RgARgUfwgzGwaGAWulUup4pm4p4z3F91UkrUeJg-Et1tMTISrGN0Lm1HtQeAACZQ5JwzNIwBmWOyCMW4AAFhTnA93mWq3efuAg2AvqtwFMcXWiMMZxJkeNJJ49fTUabTBbrET7eetIt5b5AuEQvJEqmUE7mYp3iAA)

I tried to type it `tExampleFunctionReturn<T>` with:

```
type tExampleFunctionReturn<T extends tExampleFunctionArgs> = Record<
  T[number] extends string ? T[number] : T[number][0],
  string
>
```

But it does not work.

Can someone please help me ? Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler is unable to infer that the output of `args.reduce(...)` will be a value of `ExampleFunctionReturn<T>`.  The [typings for `Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1386) only model the situation where the accumulator's type stays the same during the operation.  You are incrementally adding properties to an object, but the compiler only sees it as type `{}`, the type it infers for the initial empty object you pass in.

It is probably hopeless to try to guide the compiler to understand the gradual mutation of type from `{}` to the final output type.  The language would probably need so-called *higher-kinded types* of the sort requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) just to be able to *express* such a relationship, and who knows if inference would work even then.  But without such higher-kinded types there's not even a reasonable place to start.

Instead of trying to get the compiler to *infer* the type, you will get further if you just compute the type yourself and [*assert*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the value in question is of that type.  Here's how I'd approach it:

```
const exampleFunction = <K extends string>(
  ...args: Array<K | [K, Record<string, string>]>
) => {
  return args.reduce((acc, arg) => {
    if (typeof arg == "string") {
      return {
        ...acc,
        [arg]: "randomstring",
      };
    } else {
      return {
        ...acc,
        [arg[0]]: arg[1].result,
      };
    }
  }, {} as { [P in K]: string }); // assert here
};
```

Note that I've changed the typings from your example; I am no longer using a generic parameter `T` corresponding to the type of the `args` rest parameter.  Since all you are trying to track is the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the intended keys, I've instead made the generic type parameter `K` represent the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of these keys.  Then the `args` array elements are of type `K | [K, Record<string, string>]`.

This is easier than starting with the whole array type `T` and trying to tease the keys from it.

It also has the advantage that `K extends string` gives the compiler a hint that you want string literal types.  With your original typing, the value `["test3", {...}]` will unfortunately be widened to `string` unless you use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) or something like it.

Anyway, I have asserted that the accumulator is of a type equivalent to `Record<K, string>`, and therefore the output of `exampleFunction()` is the same type.  Let's see if it works:

```
const result = exampleFunction(
  "test1", "test2", ["test3", { result: "randomstring" }], "test4"
);
/* const result: {
    test1: string;
    test2: string;
    test3: string;
    test4: string;
} */

console.log(result.test1.toUpperCase()) // RANDOMSTRING
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwIYFsAOAbOAxArmYKAS3BgF4YAeAaXgSjjABMIZoAnIsAcwD4AKAFAwYAOnFJ23CAC4YAQXbskATxowAPjADa1ADQwASnFDsmlDl24HLPXgF1eggJTleMAN7CY7OFFzsYDCS0qK+TLjAcPz8SMDABiGuZO5eIiJEAGYw-FAqaHAg2SHkFABEttxlrmnpIr7+gZ7edSLionEJLa3aIfZyZcrMICiVZXrdIgC+ANzdU-AYEHDNrT5+AUG1a+2dE2sivVLaAAz2-cHHAIz2YXAQuBhQ+62z895TBh4LSKweOgAFGBcGDUC6VGBTZwzGAAelhwQgy3YsAAFnBfII3oJQJBYL4Hk9yHRUJgcPhCCQwPwygxoFdxjBafcoAAmRnaZnQADMjP+BMeUAGQyYIzGkPsBi5UAALNU5rCAFQwXHQdaEoWrdJ0qBXOSVOZ1HWs-VQTg8Q3alnc03m7iWkQ6mW2qxzBaK2GCHHgCAgLCiDAgbj8AVPUQ6q7hkAAVTQBXYAGFftFnK54UZ5AA5AAiAHkALIAZQAKoYAJKZgDiQA)